# implement free() function in C

Tags: c, memory-management, free

I was asked a question how to implement custom free() function in C to clear memory pointer by pointer.
I tried giving explanation with pointer arithmetic as below

```
int* ptr = malloc(sizeof(int));
int start_addr = ptr;  // Assuming ptr is at 0x0000
int end_addr = ptr+1;  // ptr+1 will increment by size of int, it will be 0x0004
int size = end_addr - start_addr;
for (int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    *(ptr+i) = 0; // clear each bit by resetting it to 0
}
```

Above will clear for pre-defined datatypes in C, but then problem statement is changed little bit again.
char* cptr = malloc(15);
How would you clear for particular size(15) give as above?
using pointer arithmetic, we can get only 1byte of address for char pointer, how do we know the end address of memory allocated for the pointer `cptr` ?

I have googled for solutions, but there are implementing `malloc()` too from sratch using struture, and then implement `my_free()` on top that custom `malloc()`.
I don't want that, we will get pointer which is already pointing to some size 15 as given in above scenario, then we should be able to clear memory pointed by that pointer.

Comment: You mention implementing `free()`, but seem to be talking about zeroing the memory. That's not what `free()` does, instead it marks the allocated memory unused, so a later `malloc()` can reuse the same space. Probably not a good idea to mix the meanings. You can't do either with just the pointer passed in to `free()`, since it doesn't contain information on the size of the allocation. That information is somewhere in the internals of the C library, or rather, your `malloc()`/`free()` implementation and not in general visible to the user program. You can't implement `free()` without `malloc()`.

Comment: It seems as if you want to implement [`freezero()`](https://man.openbsd.org/freezero#freezero) (OpenBSD is a Unix that has this function and the link goes to its manual). See [here](https://github.com/openbsd/src/blob/master/lib/libc/stdlib/malloc.c#L1598) for the implementation (which is part of the OpenBSD system C library). It basically uses the equivalent of `bzero()` to zero out the memory before handing it back to the system, but as @ilkkachu mentioned, it's using knowledge about the internal structures to do this. In a user function, you have to pass the needed information.

Comment: @Kusalananda, actually, it looks like the OpenBSD `freezero()` takes the size as an explicit argument, instead of using what malloc knows. That's of course a simpler way to implement it; one that OP here could also copy. (It's worse for the programmer, though.) I wonder if that choice has to do with having that function work regardless of the underlying malloc implementation, even if it's not the default one.

Comment: @ilkkachu I don't know how I missed that at first. I suppose that it allows for a more straightforward implementation, as you say, and possibly allows a user to use it in ways that I can't imagine at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

## Better not do that for existing malloc

So what malloc does is managing memory on the heap. When you call `malloc()`, it will look for some memory that it already manages (but is currently not in use) or will request more memory via a syscall. Anyways, `free()` is not about zeroing the memory. Internally, malloc keeps some rather intricate data structures (several of them in parallel!), that inserts pointers into the bits of memory that are free. It is a highly optimized system, including things like handling fragmentation etc..

In other words: **Don't mess with that**. The reason why all the solutions you found implement their own malloc is because that is the only way this makes sense. If you were to "insert" your custom `free()` there, you would have to exactly understand the data structures that malloc uses and how to get pointers to the next correct free chunk.

If you want to implement a custom `free()` it is probably good to understand the basics of malloc first and then implement a whole custom `malloc()` + `free()`. Keep in mind that this probably only makes sense for demonstration, you won't be as efficient as the existing implementations that have been around for a long time (except maybe for some special contexts).
Have an initial read here with the [glibc malloc internals](https://sourceware.org/glibc/wiki/MallocInternals).